# Default to lang-sql syntax highlighting for Meta.SE posts tagged with [data-explorer]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, data-explorer, syntax-highlighting

It would be nice if posts here on Meta.SE that are tagged with [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer) would automatically have SQL syntax highlighting (a la `<!-- language: lang-sql -->`) applied, in the same way that many tags on SO (like [sql]) induce a default syntax highlighting.

They say that moderators can set such a default on the tag's [info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) page; if they do so, the info page will show what the default is.

Comment: IIRC, on Stack Overflow code highlighting is automatically applied with a style provided by the tag. Maybe it's possible to enable a SQL colorisation automatically to the questions with the *data-explorer* tag.

Comment: @A.L Right, that's what I'm hoping they can do here. I'm guessing the feature isn't turned on here at the moment, but if it's not too difficult, I think it would be worth turning on.

Comment: I see now, when reading your question I thought you wanted the code `<!-- language-all: lang-sql -->` to be inserted automatically.

Comment: I've proposed an edit to clarify the, um, proposal.

Comment: @SamB Approved, but I'm reasonably sure that moderators don't have the ability to alter highlighting on _all_ sites - just those where the feature has specifically been enabled (like [so], [codereview.se], etc.). The feature is probably not enabled on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, seems reasonable.

I enabled SQL highlighting for [data-explorer](/questions/tagged/data-explorer), effective immediately.